# Sed replacing Special Characters in a string

Tags: sed, special-characters

I am having difficulties replacing a string containing special characters using sed. My old and new string are shown below

```
oldStr = "# td=(nstates=20) cam-b3lyp/6-31g geom=connectivity"
newStr = "# opt b3lyp/6-31g geom=connectivity"
```

My sed command is the following

```
sed -i 's/\# td\=\(nstates\=20\) cam\-b3lyp\/6\-31g geom\=connectivity/\# opt b3lyp\/6\-31g geom\=connectivity/g' myfile.txt
```

I dont get any errors, however there is no match. Any ideas on how to fix my patterns.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `s|# td=(nstates=20) cam-b3lyp/6-31g geom=connectivity|# opt b3lyp/6-31g geom=connectivity|g'`

you can use next to anything after `s` instead of `/`, as your expression contains slashes I used `|` instead. `-`, `=` and `#` don't have to be escaped (minus only in character sets `[`...`]`), escaped parens indicate a group, nonescaped parens are literals.

Comment: Great thanks for the reply. Clearly I am still learning sed :grin: